# Remote HDFS File Move from Secured Cluster to Non-Secured Cluster Not Working

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, kerberos

Trying to a move a file from one hdfs folder to another hdfs folder in a non secured cluster from a secured (kerborized) cluster. Both source and destination are on non secured cluster. The below code is executed in secured cluster to move the file from source hdfs folder to destination hdfs folder which are in non secured cluster.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, FileUtil, Path}
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()
import sparkSession.implicits._

val conf = new Configuration
conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://host:8020"); // This is non-secured cluster
conf.set("ipc.client.fallback-to-simple-auth-allowed", "true")
val fs = FileSystem.get(conf)

val source = new Path("/ABC/test.log")
val destination = new Path("/ABC/test")

val isMoved = FileUtil.copy(fs, source, fs, destination, true, true, conf)
```

The above code is throwing the error

```
"java.io.IOException: Server asks us to fall back to SIMPLE auth, but this client is configured to only allow secure connections"
```

I already set that config **conf.set("ipc.client.fallback-to-simple-auth-allowed", "true")** but it is not working. I would like have this config at code level instead of adding this config in core-default.xml or core-site.xml file.

Please note the below command is working when it is fired from secured cluster and the file is getting moved in non-secured cluster.

```
hdfs dfs -Dipc.client.fallback-to-simple-auth-allowed=true -mv hdfs://host:8020/ABC/test.log hdfs://host:8020/ABC/test
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the command as below and it worked.

```
hdfs dfs -Dipc.client.fallback-to-simple-auth-allowed=true -mv webhdfs://host:50070/ABC/test.log webhdfs://host:50070/ABC/test
```

Also we granted the write permission to to the secured cluster user in non-secure cluster hdfs.